# Blocking request in Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I'm trying to block some requests in a Chrome app.

I created a JavaScript listener that does this validation:

```js
chrome.webRequest.onBeforeRequest.addListener(
    {
        urls: ["*://site.com/test/*"]
    },
    ["blocking"]
);
```

But the requests are not blocking. Did I miss something in this code?

My manifest:

```json
"background": {
        "scripts": ["listener.js"],
        "persistent": true
    },
"permissions": ["tabs", "http://*/*"],
    "manifest_version": 2,
```

Comment: If you [had opened the console for the background page](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10257301/where-to-read-console-messages-from-background-js-in-a-chrome-extension/10258029#10258029), you would see the error messages about incorrect permissions. After fixing the permissions, you would see another error message that points out that the format of your `webRequest` API call is invalid.

Comment: Using this link: [blocking requests in google chrome with pattern matching](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45784247/7487135)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

It looks like you misunderstood the meaning of "blocking" here.

https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/webRequest.html#subscription

> If the optional opt_extraInfoSpec array contains the string 'blocking'
>   (only allowed for specific events), the callback function is handled
>   synchronously. That means that the request is blocked until the
>   callback function returns. In this case, the callback can return a
>   BlockingResponse that determines the further life cycle of the
>   request.

To block a request (cancel it), return `{cancel: true}` in your event handler.

For example:

```js
chrome.webRequest.onBeforeRequest.addListener(
    function() {
        return {cancel: true};
    },
    {
        urls: ["*://site.com/test/*"]
    },
    ["blocking"]
);
```

This will block all URLs matching `*://site.com/test/*`.

Also remember to declare both `webRequest` and `webRequestBlocking` permissions in your manifest.

Answer (score 12):

From **Chrome 59** you can block specific requests from Network tab of developer tools itself.

https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/04/devtools-release-notes#block-requests

Right-click on the request in the Network panel and select Block Request URL. A new Request blocking tab pops up in the Drawer, which lets you manage blocked requests.

[image: Sample]

Comment: does not work for websocket. I.e. this does not work https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/2519#issuecomment-318867289