# ChromeExtension to block the download+loading of images

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

Here is the code, in one of the most popular content blocking chrome extension.
The app is supposed to block the download of the images and does a great job at that, but lets say I go visit a page with a 70MP image it still takes a while to finish loading the page, why?

```
if (!localStorage.on) {
    localStorage.on = '1';
}

if (localStorage.on == '1') {
    chrome.browserAction.setIcon({path: "images/icon19.png"});
} else {
    chrome.browserAction.setIcon({path: "images/icon19-disabled.png"});
}

chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function(tab) {
    if (localStorage.on == '1') {
        chrome.browserAction.setIcon({path: "images/icon19-disabled.png"});
        localStorage.on = '0';
    } else {
        chrome.browserAction.setIcon({path: "images/icon19.png"});
        localStorage.on = '1';
    }
});

chrome.webRequest.onBeforeRequest.addListener(function(details) {
    if (localStorage.on == '1') {
        return {redirectUrl: "data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAEAAAABCAYAAAAfFcSJAAAACklEQVR4nGMAAQAABQABDQottAAAAABJRU5ErkJggg=="};
    }
}, {urls: ["http://*/*", "https://*/*"], types: ["image", "object"]}, ["blocking"]);

chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(function() {
    if (localStorage.on == '1') {
        chrome.tabs.insertCSS(null, {code: "img{visibility: hidden;}", runAt: "document_start"});       
    }
});
```

Comment: Could you provide a link to the extension and to the page where you experience this behavior?

Comment: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/block-image/pehaalcefcjfccdpbckoablngfkfgfgj?hl=en

Comment: http://www.conceptcarz.com/images/Jaguar/Jaguar-F-Pace-First-Edition-2015-Image-03.jpg

Comment: can anyone help me https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57971048/how-to-call-creating-new-contact-api-after-chromeextension-oauth-succeed ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The extension only intercepts requests of type `"image"` and `"object"`. This means that it will only block loading images **embedded on pages**.

If you try to load an image **directly using its URL** (such as the one you provided in your comment *http://www.conceptcarz.com/images/Jaguar/Jaguar-F-Pace-First-Edition-2015-Image-03.jpg*), the image is considered to be the main document. This means that it is requested with a resourceType of `"main_frame"` and the extension will not block its loading. It will only hide it by inserting the `"img{visibility: hidden;}"` style to the simple HTML page that Chrome generates automatically for an image.

You can verify this by inspecting the network traffic in Chrome (Ctrl+Shift+I > Network at the top > Ctr+Shift + R). When an image is loaded directly, it is not listed in the *Img* section, but in the *Doc* section.

The extension could be modified to block loading images even when opened directly by adding an `onBeforeSendHeaders` listener and blocking all traffic based on the value of `Content-Type` header. I am not sure how such a feature could be useful though (except maybe to prevent unwated data usage).

Comment: can you explain main_frame, sub_Frame etc?

Comment: also, is it faster to load a page, if I do redirect or cancel: true, I also seen cancel: block, the documentation is really poorly can't find many resources :/

Comment: @Iordanis: I was not able to find any documentation of `resourceType` either. The documentation does not even mention [all possible values](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/codesearch#chromium/src/extensions/browser/api/web_request/web_request_api_helpers.cc&q=extensions/browser/api/web_request/web_request_api_helpers.cc&sq=package:chromium&l=54) I only rely on guesses: `main_frame` probably loads the main document. `sub_frame` probably loads iframes etc.

Comment: @Iordanis
_"is it faster to load a page, if I do redirect or cancel: true, I also seen cancel: block"_ I don't think there is such a thing as `cancel:block`. You seem to be confusing `"blocking"` and `cancel: true` here. [See this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18158416/5695459). Since the code above redirects to a `data:` URI with an embedded blank 1x1 image and does not lead to any network activity, the performance difference between this redirection and blocking the request completely using 'cancel: true' should be negligible.

Comment: sorry but can anyone help me https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57971048/how-to-call-creating-new-contact-api-after-chromeextension-oauth-succeed?