# Request Blocking Using Javascript?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, testing, xmlhttprequest, testcafe

How to block requests from a certain URL using JavaScript? For example, the manual way to do so on chrome will be to open the inspect page, go to network and block from there. But I need to block requests from certain URLs for an automated test that i am writing in JavaScript (using testcafe, if that offers any help).

Here are screenshots of manually blocking a request from chrome, I want to do the same thing automatically in my test/JavaScript:
[ScreenShot1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/USRx1.png)

[image]

Thank you.

Edit:
I tired following this post: [Blocking request in Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18158297/blocking-request-in-chrome)
but for some reason i always keep getting an error stating that chrome is undefined when I use chrome.webRequest

Comment: you might want to check this out https://github.com/cyrus-and/chrome-remote-interface/wiki/Intercept-and-block-requests-by-URL

Comment: Are you trying to use an extension to block requests?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Blocking request in Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18158297/blocking-request-in-chrome)

Comment: @AbhishekAnand, I checked that already and tried it with changing the return pathname.match(/\.(css|png|svg)$/); to return pathname.match(/cdn/); to mach the blocking case in my screenshots. it didnt work

Comment: @VitalyMenchikovsky I tried this, I always seem to get an error when using chrome.webRequest
it says chrome is undefined.

Comment: @guest271314 what do you mean? Sorry i dont get the question.

Comment: What do you mean by "block requests"?

Comment: @guest271314 I dont know really how to explain it. Best follow the screenshots
hmm, ok try this:
-in chrome open a new tab, then press CTRL+SHIFT+i
-Navigate to the network tab
-now go to any website and you will see the network tab page fill up, right click on one of them and you will have an option to block by URL, then this URL will be added to a filter at the bottom of the page. you can also use the + sign to add more URL with wildcards like in the screenshot

Comment: At Chromium/Chrome you can set a Policy, see [chrome Pop-up blocker when to re-check after allowing page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40282861/chrome-pop-up-blocker-when-to-re-check-after-allowing-page/)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [nock](https://github.com/node-nock/nock) library, which allows you to intercept requests and process them as you wish.

Answer (score 0):

To achieve that you need to **intercept & block** the request originating from the response page to load ads.
What you are looking for is the core principle of an `ad-blocker`which is possible with a browser extension.

so create a `manifest.json` with

```js
{
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "name": "REQblock",
    "version": "2.3.4",
    "permissions": ["webRequest", "webRequestBlocking", "<all_urls>"],
    "background": {
      "scripts": ["script.js"]
    }    
}
```

and then create `script.json`

```js
function getBlacklistUrls(){    
    var  urls = [
    "*://cdn.sstatic.net/*",
    "*://*.twitter.com/*",
    "*://*.youtube.com/*"
    ];

    return urls; 
};

(async () => {
  var dummyCallback = function (details) {
    return {
      cancel: true
    };
  };

  var list = getBlacklistUrls();
  var blockedUrls = { urls: list };

  //Add Listener
  chrome.webRequest.onBeforeRequest
    .addListener(dummyCallback,blockedUrls,["blocking"]);
})();
```

The above chrome extension will block all url returning from `getBlacklistUrls()`. If you still don't undestand what chrome extensions are and how to load & enable check my ad-blocker [AdvertShield](https://github.com/Killercodes/Advert-Shield) at `github` and follow the wiki as how to install it.

The result will come something like this [image]