# How to block image from loading in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, request, blocking

I am changing src of all images to '' using mutation observer. But browser is making the request to that image URL. How to block image requests from the browser?

Below is the code.

```
const observer = new MutationObserver(mutations => {
    mutations.forEach(({
        addedNodes
    }) => {
        addedNodes.forEach(node => {
            if( node.tagName == "IMG" ){
                node.setAttribute("data-src",src);
                node.removeAttribute('src');
            }                                      
        });
    });
});
observer.observe(document.documentElement, {
    childList: true,
    subtree: true
});
```

Comment: Where is your question?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Request Blocking Using Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48295525/request-blocking-using-javascript)

Comment: Now check my question once.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that any markup like this: `<img src="[IMG]" />` is going to trigger a request. You need to start with  `<img data-src="[IMG]" />` and then introduce `src` rather than vice versa.

Comment: we don't have option to set `data-src` in html, as we don't have control over html code. We are creating a third party script to block some elements from loading.